# Mongod not running.. E NETWORK [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, ubuntu, mongoose

I am developing a webapp in mean.io and i was following this video tutoial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI

I already have mongodb installed in my ubuntu system and as in tutorial installed mongoose via `sudo npm install mongoose` (I had to give `sudo` system prompted me)

And after installing it i opened up another terminal and typed `mongod`

See its output

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~$ mongod
2015-07-14T12:22:48.497+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-07-14T12:22:48.497+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-07-14T12:22:48.498+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in  initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-07-14T12:22:48.498+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Then I searched for the fixes in askubuntu and stackoverflow

I typed this

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~$ netstat -an | grep :27017
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56348         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56350         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56349         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56351         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56347         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56364         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56349         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56351         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56364         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56350         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56347         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56348         ESTABLISHED
```

Then

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~$ ps aux | grep mongod
mongodb   1067  0.5  1.2 697684 96512 ?        Ssl  10:06   0:43 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
mukund    5358  0.0  0.0  15948  2280 pts/9    S+   12:21   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod
```

Then as said in the fix I killed p.No 5358 and again ran `mongod`

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~$ mongod
2015-07-14T12:22:48.497+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-07-14T12:22:48.497+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-07-14T12:22:48.498+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-07-14T12:22:48.498+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

What is wrong here? Did installing mongoose via npm command caused the issue?

One more thing to mention is that i can still connect to mogodb database via `mongo` command

Some one please help

Ans at last here is what i did,

reinstalled mongodb using

`sudo apt-get install mongodb`

then i ran `mongod` gave me error saying path not set, so i set the path.

Then ran `mongo` and everything worked!

Comment: If `mongod` is already running, you don't need to start it again. Just start using Mongoose.

Comment: can i restart mongod?

Comment: looks like the process you wanted to kill was with ID 1067 and not 5358?

Comment: Your OS probably provides you with tools to stop/start/restart mongod properly (could be `service restart mongodb` on Ubuntu, not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `apt-get` to install mongodb, it creates a service that automatically starts when your computer boots. It's also started as soon as the install completes. You can stop, start or restart it using `sudo service start/stop/restart mongodb` (it may be "mongod" on your system)

If you want to change how it starts up, have a look in /etc/init.d for the service config. The actual mongo config that the service uses is found in /etc/mongod.conf. If you look there, you should see a line that looks like

```
 dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
```

This defines where the database is actually stored.